# Is the Blu-ray/DVD question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am looking at this question, https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71/, and wondering if it's a good fit here. It feels more an economy subject.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that it is not on-topic.  It is a question of business-models, marketing strategy, product management, technology ... very little to do with the content of Movies.

Technology does impact Movies - as resolutions go up and new technologies like 3D or all digital filming starts to impact the design of movies this is on-topic - but this cost of the disks is not.

Answer (score 1):

I say it *should* be on-topic.

We seem to be (whether this is adviseable or not) preferring to create *format specific* rather than *genre specific* sites. (i.e: literature, movies, comic books, television).  Sci-fi is the outlier in that respect.

In my mind it makes no sense to tell someone it doesn't matter where they ask a question about a sci-fi movie's content, but that they definitely can't ask their question about the business of movies on Movies.

Comment: I think you have an argument here - its the 'business of movies', but ... I still think I fall on the 'off topic' side.  Its not a discussion about the technical merits of the format - how it aids/or damages the experience of watching a movie.  I would be happy to have questions about 3D for example - but this a question about the economics and marketing of a single format that movie's appear on.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's a terrible question, basically: "I assume price is a linear function of costs.  Blu-ray costs less.  Why is price higher?  Provide costs as proof."  It should be closed because it's a terrible question and not be a litmus test for people to apply too broadly about what's on topic at all really.  I VtC as NARQ but this is my objection to the other 4 votes on record here.